# Can't find freshly installed package / application

Tags: apt

I recently switched from Windows 10 to Linux. I am trying to install **Prolog** and I followed the installation instructions on https://www.swi-prolog.org/build/PPA.html. I had no errors during the commands `apt-add repository`, `apt-get update` and `apt-get install swi-prolog`.

I expected just to see **Prolog** in my applications, but isn't listed and can't be found via the search. I'm very confused because I don't know where to look. In Windows I could look in my **Program Files** directory or in the **installed software** display. Do I have to find and start it via the **Terminal**? Isn't the installation finished? Please help.

Answer (score 3):

From the website manual, it says to type "swipl" into the terminal (without quotes).

https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=quickstart

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, the swipl command does work. But I used Prolog in windows before and it had it's own UI. I was expecting the same here tbh.

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with the software, so I don't know if either there is another command to start a GUI or if it's not included in Linux.

Comment: I thought so. Thanks anyway. Big help :)!